# Usual vs. cohomological Brauer groups of Calabi-Yau threefolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the preprint arXiv:math/0505432v1
by Batyrev and Kreuser I have found (on pages 2 and 10) the claim that 
"by a recent result of Kresch and Vistoli [arXiv:math/0301249]"
the (usual) Brauer group of a Calabi-Yau threefold is isomorphic 
to its cohomological Brauer group. However, in that preprint of 
Kresch and Vistoli I have not found a word about Calabi-Yau or anything.
(Admittedly, it is about Brauer groups). Could anyone help me to 
clear the mess?

P.S. For what I know, if there is always an isomorphism is a big open problem
which is only settled in a few special cases. So, I suppose, 
if this is known indeed for Calabi-Yau threefolds (for 10 years by now), then
every expert must be aware of it.

Comment: It follows from  a theorem of Gabber that for any quasi-projective variety the usual Brauer group is equal to the cohomological Brauer group. See, for example http://www.math.columbia.edu/~dejong/papers/2-gabber.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was proved by Gabber and De Jong that the cohomological Brauer group of a quasi-compact scheme with an ample invertible sheaf equals its Brauer group. Our preprint does not contain this result.